# If a function had an infinite limit at a point, what kind of discontinuity would it have?

Tags: real-analysis

Taking this example: $\frac{1}{x^{2/3}}$ at $x = 0$ is clearly infinite as its limit. It seems just by looking at the graph, that it is continuous at this point but is this true for any such infinite derivative points? If there are cases that they are discontinuous, would they always be mixed discontinuities?

Comment: "it is continuous at this point" Which point are you referring to? The mentioned function is not *defined* at $x=0$.

Comment: Oh that's right. Are there any examples that have infinite limits at a continuous point?

Comment: What does your book define "discontinuity"? What are the "kinds" of discontinuities mentioned in your book? Have you seen something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Classification)?

Comment: Yes that's precisely what I meant: removable, jump, and mixed

Comment: No, "mixed" is not in the linked article; the third one there is "essential" discontinuity.// What is the definition of "mixed" discontinuity in your book? //The question in the title is almost trivial when the definitions are clear.

Comment: Yes by "mixed" I do mean "essential" meaning that one of the sides of the limits does not exist.

Comment: One-sided limits in the first two kinds are both finite; so the only possibility must be the third kind. What is the confusion/question?

Comment: So basically, if we had a function that had an infinite derivative at a point, what we would be able to comment on its continuity, if any.

Comment: You are thinking *too* hard. Simply look at the *definitions* of different kinds of discontinuities.// Or are you asking a question different from the one in the title?

Comment: "had an infinite derivative at a point", there is no such thing called "infinite derivative".// It would be much easier to give you guidelines if you tell the readers what book you are using. Every word/concept used should be based on solid definitions.

Comment: Yes I suppose it is a different question because my original title assumes discontinuity while this one just asks us to comment anything about continuity.

Comment: What exactly is "this" question? Can you please state it clearly?

Comment: Ok so "if a function has an infinite derivative at a point, what can we say about the continuity of this function at the point, if any?"

Comment: Again, this is *not* a valid question because there is no such thing as "infinite derivative". Do you make this up? Or is it from a book?

Comment: It's from a book.. it is literally what it says..

Comment: You are either probably reading a very bad one, or you missed some of the definitions in the book... Can you please give the name of the book?

Comment: Ah so I'm not sure what book it's from since it was a homework assignment.. but it is from a book according to our instructor.

Comment: Could you ask your instructor which book is it? This seems extremely suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

A function cannot be discontinuous nor continuous at a point that is not in the domain of said function. $0$ is not in the domain of the function you are mentioning. Hence, it is neither discontinuous nor continuous at $0$. $0$ is what we would call a singularity of the function, specifically called a branch point. This is a bit outside the scope of your question, though, since classifying singularities requires complex analysis.

Comment: Yes so our original question was what can we say about continuity at that point if any? So I guess I would say it is neither continuous nor discontinuous?

Comment: @TreausreDragon Correct, and furthermore, you can say it has an infinite singularity at $0$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll probably skip the infinite singularity part since we haven't even talked about those yet.